# Can you use casing molding for baseboard molding?

Tags: flooring, trim, baseboard

I am curious if there are any reasons not to use a casing molding (typically used for doors or windows) as base molding along the floor?  The casing molding is made out of pine which seems to be used for a lot of base molding as well.  The casing molding appears to be thicker (11/16" instead of 1/2" or 9/16").  They distinguish them on the sites that sell them, so that's why I ask the question.  The casing molding is thicker (which could help with any large flooring gaps left by floating floor) and is a bit cheaper.

Casing molding:

[image: Casing molding option]

Base molding:

[image: Base board molding option]

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, it really is a style choice and nothing prevents you from switching the two.  But one thing not pointed out and you probably didn't notice, is the edge that meets the floor.  For baseboards, the bottom edge is square, where casing typically round the edges (which will not make as nice of a transition from the molding to the floor if installing over wood or tile).

Answer (score 2):

There's no real issue with it, except only that the more complex the profile, the harder it is to clean. If you use a gloss or semi-gloss finish, you can probably wipe dust up pretty easily. But a flat or matte paint or finish will make it harder to clean fine dust off a more complex molding profile. The casing doesn't get as much dust when installed vertically in a doorway.

Answer (score 0):

It's purely a stylistic choice.  Trim is decorative.

If you're buying it based on it being thicker and needing to cover gaps in your floating floor, you installed the floor wrong...